# How do you test a React function component state with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am only starting with unit testing now and the course I am following has the following syntax for a test:

`expect(app.state().gifts).toEqual([])`

This is the syntax for the use of class components but that will be deprecated soon so I am using React function components instead.

How do you accomplish the same test with hooks?

Thanks

Comment: By React hooks do you mean React function components? It sounds like you are asking how to test function components. It's at this point I would suggest ditching enzyme and switch over to using React-Testing-Library for your UI component testing needs.

Comment: You seem to have clarified that you mean testing function-based components, then accepted an answer that covers testing hooks. That's quite confusing. Note that you shouldn't have been asserting on state in class-based components, either; test _behaviour_, not implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [react-hooks-testing-library](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/) and test your hooks as well. [Basic Hooks](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/basic-hooks)

Example :

**useDisclosure.ts**

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const useDisclosure = (initial = false) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(initial);
  const open = React.useCallback(() => setIsOpen(true), []);
  const close = React.useCallback(() => setIsOpen(false), []);
  const toggle = React.useCallback(() => setIsOpen((state) => !state), []);

  return { isOpen, open, close, toggle };
};
```

**useDisclosure.test.ts**

```
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { useDisclosure } from '../useDisclosure';

test('should open the state', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useDisclosure());
  expect(result.current.isOpen).toBe(false);
  act(() => {
    result.current.open();
  });
  expect(result.current.isOpen).toBe(true);
});

test('should close the state', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useDisclosure());
  expect(result.current.isOpen).toBe(false);
  act(() => {
    result.current.close();
  });
  expect(result.current.isOpen).toBe(false);
});

test('should toggle the state', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useDisclosure());
  expect(result.current.isOpen).toBe(false);
  act(() => {
    result.current.toggle();
  });
  expect(result.current.isOpen).toBe(true);
  act(() => {
    result.current.toggle();
  });
  expect(result.current.isOpen).toBe(false);
});

test('should define initial state', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useDisclosure(true));
  expect(result.current.isOpen).toBe(true);
  act(() => {
    result.current.toggle();
  });
  expect(result.current.isOpen).toBe(false);
});
```